# SD Card disapears after a while

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-d7000, sdcard

I have the Problem, that my SD card disappears when I use my Nikon for a while. This means that it suddenly show me a  `[-E-]` instead of the Number of remaining Photos to make.

I don't know if it is a Problem of the camera or if the Card is defect...

Does anybody have any idea what I should do, because it's pretty annoying when I shoot photos and then notice, that the camera/sd-card is bugging again.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you do when you notice this, and then what happens?

Comment: I take the sd-card out, and put it back again. and then it works... i noticed the same on the second sd-card slot (with the same sd-card)

Comment: Have you tried another card?

Answer (score 6):

First make sure the metal contacts on the card are clean, and reformat the card in the camera using the menu. I assume you've done these things but it doesn't hurt to double check.

Since you get the same behavior in both card slots, it seems likely the card is damaged. They are relatively cheap — get a new one, preferably a higher-end name brand. If you see trouble with another card, send the camera in for cleaning and repair.